# Set/Access WCF Class level properties from IOS request

Tags: ios, objective-c, wcf

There are hundreds of methods in my WCF service and one general property that i want to access in almost all methods so i made it class level property instead of method parameter.

Now i want to set my class property from IOS call, so i can easily use in any method

A dummy of my code is here:

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "", SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehaviorAttribute(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class MobileService
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string myToken { get; set; }


        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string GetData1()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myToken))
            {
                return string.Format("Invalid Token");
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Format("Valid");
            }

        }
    }
```

Please help me to access/set this property from IOS, or you can suggest better idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Services generally don't have properties - if you need to access something like that you'll most likely need to write a method (operation contract) to do so.

Comment: Yes i know that. but i have hundreds of methods and i don't want to repeat code in each method. because i run a bunch of code on behalf of this property on each call. so can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with help of Request-headers and Constructor.

```
    public MobileService()
    {
         myToken = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["myToken"];
         ...
    }
```

Now i can use it any where in service.